# Why does saving data result in an invalid value for inexistent field 'ERROR_CODE'?

Tags: sql, delphi, ado

In Delphi XE I have a `TClientDataSet`, which gets its data from a `TADOQuery`, I am appending a new entry to it. The code looks something like this:

```
with DataModule.MyClientDataSet begin
  Append;
  FieldByName('ID').AsInteger := SomeID;
  FieldByName('STRING').AsString := SomeString;
  FieldByName('DATE').AsDateTime := SomeDate;
  Post;
  ApplyUpdates(-1);
end;
```

The SQL behind the client data set is a simple

```sql
SELECT *
FROM mytable
WHERE x = :x
  AND y = :y
```

where `x` and `y` are strings.

The values for the variables are all set, the only irregular thing I can see is that the date is set to 1899-12-30.

And the call to `ApplyUpdates(-1);` results in the following exception:

> -2147217900 is not a valid value for field 'ERROR_CODE'. The allowed range is 0 to 4294967295

The table *doesn't* have a column `ERROR_CODE`. So what does this error message actually mean?

Comment: No, the table doesn't have any triggers.

Comment: Have you specified those parameters, `x` and `y` I mean?

Comment: `x` and `y` are specified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a bug in DataSetProvider in Delphi XE which was fixed with one of its hotfixes
http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41312#3RADStudioXEHotfixforRAIDQC

The same bug has also been seen in Delphi XE2 and was fixed with Update 3
http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=88928

Here is another QC report of this bug for Delphi XE
http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=100723

Comment: The hotfix worked. Thanks! I added my Delphi version to the question and removed the question for it from your answer.

Comment: I'm glad this helped you fix your problem. And just a small hint for next time when you encounter strange error which doesen't seem to originate from your code. Use Google! That is how I managed to find the answer for you :-)

Comment: I did search (using DuckDuckGo) before I asked here, though it seems I didn't use the right keywords, because the hotfix page was not in the search results.

Comment: Sometimes using keywords won't return you correct answer especially if those keywords are often used for something else. In such case it is sometimes usefull to input whole error message as search query. And that is exactly what I did to get to this answer.